# Displaying loading animation while waiting

Tags: php, laravel

I have a button like so

```
{!! link_to_route('jobs.createJob', 'Create Job', $job->id, array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) !!}
```

So this route calls a function which does something like this

```
public function createJob(Job $job) {
    $createJob = Helper::createNewJob($job);
    $createJobXML = new \SimpleXMLElement($createJob);
    if($createJobXML->Status == 'OK') {
        $job->jobNumber = $createJobXML->Job->ID;
        if($job->update()) {
            $assignStaff = Helper::assignStaffToJob($job);
            $assignStaffXML = new \SimpleXMLElement($assignStaff);
            if($assignStaffXML->Status == 'OK'){
                $createQuoteForJob = Helper::createQuoteForJob($job);
                $createQuoteForJobXML = new \SimpleXMLElement($createQuoteForJob);
                if($createQuoteForJobXML->Status == 'OK'){
                    $job->quoteId = $createQuoteForJobXML->ID;
                    if($job->update()) {
                        return View::make('jobs.show', compact('job'));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return View::make('campaigns.show', compact('job'));
}
```

So there is quite a lot going on which involves hitting several API methods to insert data into a system.  This process can sometimes take a few seconds, and I do not want them being able to click the submit button again, so I want to show them a loading screen while this happens.

If I was making this request via ajax I could simple use ajaxStart and ajaxComplete.  However, I am not using ajax, so is there another way I could do this within Laravel 5?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a Laravel specific issue. This is agnostic of language when you're dealing with a server-side problem like that.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that

Comment: You can call the laravel cotroller function in  Ajax and display a waiting image before havig the request response

Comment: @KubiRoazhon - From the question "If I was making this request via ajax I could simple use ajaxStart and ajaxComplete. However, **I am not using ajax**, so is there another way I could do this within Laravel 5?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an onclick handler to the button so that when it's clicked, it gets disabled.

```
{!! link_to_route('jobs.createJob', 'Create Job', $job->id, array('class' => 'btn btn-info', 'onclick' => 'disableButton(this)')) !!}

function disableButton(ele)
{
    ele.disabled = true;

    // And display loading animation here if you need.
}
```